# c# how to call a (non static) method in another class using a delegate or function pointer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in C# and I'm a little confused on this point here. Each ship has an identical AI Class that handles moving my spaceships around. And then each ship has it's own class, and in that class is a non-static function that checks if its about to smash into anything. Each ship has a different implementation of this. I did not think to derive them all from a base class, although I see how that might have helped in this situation.

It's pretty easy for me to get a reference to the ships in the AI Class. This is Unity so I can just GetComponent and if the ship is null it doesn't exist. So I thought to keep it cleaner, instead of checking for null for all the ships each time I want to check collision that I would just add a function pointer in the AI class and set it to the collision detect method in the ship class. But I must not understand how delagates work in C#, is this even possible like is in C++?  All the examples I've seen so far are static, or don't seem to be pointing to member methods.

As  code example I thought something like this might work, but it complains that I am treating collisionDetected like a variable when it is a type. So I guess I'm not sure what I'm doing here.

```
private delegate bool collisionDetected(Vector3 direction, float maxDistance);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //moveToTarget(target);
        fighter = gameObject.GetComponent<FighterBot>();
        if (fighter != null) {
            collisionDetected = fighter.checkCollision;
        }
```

Comment: think of delegate like a typedef in c. you still need to add a field to your class, e.g.: `private collisionDetected myCollisionDetected;` then you can assign to it: `myCollisionDetected = fighter.checkCollision;`.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you that was the perfect explanation for me, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

A [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates) is just a **template** for a method signature (similar to an `interface` for types).

You still need something using this `delegate` type like e.g.

```
public collisionDetected fighterCollisionDetected;

void Start()
{
    //moveToTarget(target);
    fighter = gameObject.GetComponent<FighterBot>();
    if (fighter != null) {
        fighterCollisionDetected = fighter.checkCollision;
    }
}
```

And later on

```
if(fighterCollisionDetected?.Invoke(direction, distance))
{
    ...
}
```